# How do you write the Wightman function $\langle\phi(t_1)\phi(t_2)\rangle$ for a massive scalar field in position space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator

For a free real scalar field $\phi(t,\mathbf{x})$, we define the Wightman function as:
$$
W(t_1,t_2) \equiv \langle 0 | \phi(t_1,\mathbf{x}_1) \phi(t_2,\mathbf{x}_2) | 0 \rangle
$$
I'm suppressing the position labels for clarity. And the Feynman propagator is defined as:
$$
F(t_1,t_2) \equiv \langle 0 | \mathcal{T}\big( \phi(t_1,\mathbf{x}_1) \phi(t_2,\mathbf{x}_2) \big) | 0 \rangle
$$
where $\mathcal{T}$ is the time-ordering "operator". This can be expressed in terms of the Wightman function as
$$
F(t_1,t_2) = \Theta(t_1-t_2) W(t_1,t_2) + \Theta(t_2-t_1) W(t_2,t_1)
$$

These functions have the properties
$$
W(t_1,t_2) = W(t_2,t_1)^{\ast} \\
F(t_1,t_2) = F(t_2,t_1)
$$

I *believe* that it follows from this (correct me if I'm wrong):
$$
W(t_1,t_2) = \mathrm{Re}\big[ F(t_1,t_2) \big] + i \mathrm{sign}(t_1-t_2) \mathrm{Im}\big[ F(t_1,t_2) \big] \\
F(t_1,t_2) = \mathrm{Re}\big[ W(t_1,t_2) \big] + i \mathrm{sign}(t_1-t_2) \mathrm{Im}\big[ W(t_1,t_2) \big] \\
$$

It is well known that the position-space representation of $F$ for a massive $m\neq 0$ field is:
$$
F(t_1,t_2)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 + i \epsilon } } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 + i \epsilon } \right)
$$
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind (of order $1$).

**QUESTION:** Is the following true?
$$
W(t_1,t_2)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 } } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 } \right)
$$

I would be inclined to believe this, since for a *massless* $m=0$ field, the corresponding functions are:
$$
F(t_1,t_2) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{-(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 + i \epsilon} \\
W(t_1,t_2) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{-(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is positive and the result can be proved separately form the expression you quoted for the Feynman propagator, just expanding smeared quantum fields into definite-momentum modes and computing weak limits ($\epsilon$-prescriptions). However a formal proof of how the formula of Feynman propagator gives rise to that of the two-point function can be obtained as follows (there are mathematical details to fix) 
From $$
F(t_1,t_2) = \Theta(t_1-t_2) W(t_1,t_2) + \Theta(t_2-t_1) W(t_2,t_1) \tag{1}
$$
you have, where the bar denotes the complex conjugation,
$$
\overline{F(t_1,t_2)} = \Theta(t_1-t_2) \overline{W(t_1,t_2)} + \Theta(t_2-t_1) \overline{W(t_2,t_1)}\:.
$$
However, assuming the quantum fields Hermitian, you also have 
$$\overline{W(t_1,t_2)}= W(t_2,t_1)$$
so that
$$
\overline{F(t_1,t_2)} = \Theta(t_1-t_2) {W(t_2,t_1)} + \Theta(t_2-t_1) {W(t_1,t_2)}\:.\tag{2}
$$
Multiplying (1) for $\Theta(t_1-t_2)$ and (2) for $\Theta(t_2-t_1)$ we obtain
$$
\Theta(t_1-t_2)F(t_1,t_2) = \Theta(t_1-t_2) W(t_1,t_2) \tag{1'}
$$
and
$$
\Theta(t_2-t_1)\overline{F(t_1,t_2)} = \Theta(t_2-t_1) {W(t_1,t_2)}\:.\tag{2'}
$$
Summing side-by-side
$$\Theta(t_1-t_2)F(t_1,t_2)
+ \Theta(t_2-t_1)\overline{F(t_1,t_2)} = (\Theta(t_1-t_2) + \Theta(t_2-t_1))W(t_1,t_2)\:.  $$
In other words
$$W(t_1,t_2) = \Theta(t_1-t_2)F(t_1,t_2)
+ \Theta(t_2-t_1)\overline{F(t_1,t_2)}\tag{3}\:.$$
It is not difficult that this identity produces 
$$
W(t_1,t_2)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 } } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 } \right)\tag{4}
$$
from
$$
F(t_1,t_2)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 + i \epsilon } } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 + i \epsilon } \right)\:.
$$
In particular since both the square root and $K_1$ have the property that $\overline{f(z)}= f(\overline{z})$ in the considered branch of their domains (which are Riemann surfaces)
$$
\overline{F(t_1,t_2)}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 - i \epsilon } } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 - i \epsilon } \right)\:.
$$
If $t_2-t_1>0$, we can replace $i \epsilon $ for  $2i \epsilon(t_2-t_1)$ producing
 $$
\Theta(t_2-t_1)\overline{F(t_1,t_2)}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m\Theta(t_2-t_1)}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 - 2i \epsilon (t_2-t_1)} } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2 - 2i \epsilon (t_2-t_1)} \right)\:.
$$
Namely,
 $$
\Theta(t_2-t_1)\overline{F(t_1,t_2)}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m\Theta(t_2-t_1)}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} \right)\:.
$$
The same argument analogously produces
 $$
\Theta(t_1-t_2)F(t_1,t_2)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{m\Theta(t_1-t_2)}{4\pi^2 \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} } K_{1}\left( m \sqrt{ -(t_1-t_2-i\epsilon)^2 + |\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2|^2} \right)\:.
$$
Using (3), we find just your identity (4).